# Zend Framework and Jquery :: Ajax - Check if id is available - How to?

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

On a given form **input field**, **on blur**, I would like to check if that input value is valid. 
To know if that id is valid or not, I need to **query the database**. 
If it's not valid, a message should appear next to the input field indicating that the option is not valid.

I'm over Zend Framework, however, this is my very first solo Ajax experience.

Can I have a skeleton about how something like this could be implemented please ?

I'm a little aware that something like this should be used...

```
if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
...
```

but I really need a help here. :s

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should take care while handling AJAX requests in Zend Framework - disable the view/MVC layout component.

In your action,

```
    public function validateAction()
    {

    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    //Disable the view/layout
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);

    //Receive the value from the form
    $inputValue = $this->_getParam('name');

    //Access your model and validate the data.

    $model = new Model();
    $result = $model->isValid($inputValue);


    $myArray = array(
                 'result'=>$result
               );

    $jsonData = Zend_Json::encode($myArray);
//Send the result back to the client
    $this->response->appendBody($jsonData);
    }
    }
```

Receive this JSON object from client side(use jQuery), process it and show the appropriate message.

A similar question - [How do you make Zend Framework NOT render a view/layout when sending an AJAX response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498692/how-do-you-make-zend-framework-not-render-a-view-layout-when-sending-an-ajax-resp)